# Gradient does not exist at a point or just vanishes (zero vectors)

Tags: functions, continuity, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

Given the function
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac {xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, & x^2+y^2≠ 0 \\
0, & x=y=0
\end{cases}$$
find its gradient at point $(0,0)$.

If I had the first part of the function only, I would calculate the partial derivatives first:
$$\nabla f(x,y)=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y),\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\right) =
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-\frac{x^2y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{x^2+y^2}\\
\frac{x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-\frac{xy^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{x^2+y^2}\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{y^3}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\\
\frac{x^3}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then would find the gradient value at point $(0,0)$, which of course would not exist since the partial derivatives are not defined at this specific point.

However, my function is defined at the point of interest differently, namely as $0$. The partial derivatives of this function are also equal to $0$. Thus, the gradient is also a zero vector 
$$\nabla f(0,0)=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0),\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)\right)=(0,0).$$

Is this line of reasoning correct or are there any other subtleties pertaining to the continuity and differentiability of functions?

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$$
\frac{{f\left( {0 + h,0} \right) - f\left( {0,0} \right)}}
{h} = \frac{{\frac{{h \cdot 0}}
{{h^2  + 0^2 }} - 0}}
{h} = \frac{{0 - 0}}
{h} = 0
$$
it follows, by definition, that
$$
\frac{{\partial f}}
{{\partial x}}\left( {0,0} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {0 + h,0} \right) - f\left( {0,0} \right)}}
{h} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} 0 = 0
$$
The same is true for 
$$
\frac{{\partial f}}
{{\partial y}}\left( {0,0} \right)
$$
which is still $0$. Therefore you have that your gradient is $(0,0)$.